# How to use in curl command data from file?

Tags: bash, curl

I have a text file containing variables of fqdn and hostname. File looks like this

```
first_fqnd    first_hostname
second_fqdn     second_hostname
.....      .....
```

I have to update some data using curl in a bash script, but I have to take fqdn and hostname from this text file and make a curl for every pair fqdn and hostname.

My curl should be like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPUT "https://pup.pnet.pl/api/hosts/**fqdn from file**" -d '{"host":{"name": "**hostname from file**"}}' --cacert bundle.pem --cert xxx-pem.cer --key xxx-privkey.pem
```

How can I pass these variables from file to curl? I've thought about using awk, but I don't know how to use it in curl command

Answer (score 5):

Use a `while` construct to read the lines of file and put whitespace separated parameters as two relevant variables, `fqdn` and `hostn`:

```
while read fqdn hostn; do
    curl -H .... -XPUT "https://pup.pnet.pl/api/hosts/${fqdn}" \
      -d '{"host":{"name": "'"${hostn}"'"}}' --cacert ....; done <file.txt
```

Comment: You don't need backslash after `do`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read fqdn hostname; do
    curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPUT \
        "https://pup.pnet.pl/api/hosts/${fqdn}" \
        -d '{"host":{"name": "'${hostname}'}}' --cacert bundle.pem \
        --cert xxx-pem.cer --key xxx-privkey.pem
done <input_file.txt
```

The `while read fqdn hostname` will take input from Standard Input, line by line, splitting it by Bash's Internal Field Separator into "column" variables `$fqdn` and `$hostname`. See [Catching User Input](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) for more information.